# Random characters enter the file I am writing in c++

Tags: c++

```
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <fstream.h>
#include <string.h>



class mobile
{
int id;
float price;
char *model,*brand;
public:
int getId()
{
    return id;
}
float getPrice(){return price;}
mobile()
{
    brand = new char[5];
    model = new char[5];
    id = 0;
    price = 0.0;
}
void addDetail()
{
    cout<<"\nEnter the mobile ID ";cin>>id;
    cout<<"\nEnter the Price of mobile ";cin>>price;
    cout<<"\nEnter the Brand name of mobile ";cin>>brand;
    cout<<"\nEnter the Model of mobile ";cin>>model;
    ofstream file("database.txt",ios::app);
    char c=' ',n='\n';
    file<<id<<c;
    file<<price<<c;
    file<<brand<<c;
    file<<model<<n;
    file.close();

}

char* getbrand(){return brand;}
char* getModel(){return model;}
~mobile()
{
    delete brand;
    delete model;
}

};

void count()
{
int counter = 0;
char c;
ifstream file("database.txt");
file.seekg(0,ios::beg);
if(!file)cout<<"File not present";
while(file)
{
    file.get(c);
    if(c == '\n')
    {
        counter++;
    }
}
cout<<"The no of entries "<<counter;
file.close();
}

void addMobile()
{
char *model,*brand;

mobile m;
m.addDetail();    
}

void EditMobile()
{
fstream file;
char* brand,*model;
file.open("database.txt",ios::in);
brand = new char;
model = new char;
char c;
int id,pos;
float price;
float f;
if(!file)cout<<"File not present";
else
{


file>>id;cout<<"ID :"<<id<<endl;
file>>price;cout<<"Price :"<<price<<endl;
file>>brand;cout<<"Brand :"<<brand<<endl;
file>>model;cout<<"Model :"<<model<<endl;

}

delete brand;
delete model;
file.close();

}

void admin()
{

char* userpassword;
userpassword = new char;
char* pass;
pass = new char;

cout<<"\n\nEnter the Password";
cin>>userpassword;
fstream fin;
fin.open("password.txt",ios::in | ios::out);
if(!fin)
cout<<"\n\nFile does not exist";
else
{
fin>>pass;
if(strcmp(userpassword,pass) == 0)
{
    char ch;

    count();
    clrscr();
    cout<<"\n\nAcces Granted!!\n\n\tWelcome";
    cout<<"\n\n1.Add a Mobile.";
    cout<<"\n2.Edit a Mobile.";
    cout<<"\n3.Delete a Mobile.";
    cout<<"\n4.View the Database.\n\nEnter Your Choice ";
    ch = getch();
    switch(ch)
    {
    case '1':
        addMobile();
        break;
    case '2':
        EditMobile();
        break;
    case '3':
        //deleteMobile();
        break;

    }
}
else
{
    cout<<"\n\nAcces Denied";
    return;
}
}

fin.close();
delete userpassword;
}
int main()
{
char choice;
clrscr();
cout<<"Welcome to Mobile Store management Program";
cout<<"\n1.Find a Mobile.";
cout<<"\n2.Know Price.";
cout<<"\n3.Know Description.";
cout<<"\n4.Administrator Login.\n\nEnter Your Choice";
choice = getch();
switch(choice)
{
case '1':

    break;
case '4':
    admin();
    break;
}
getch();
return 0;
}
```

Now in the output I type:

```
Acces Granted!!

        Welcome

1.Add a Mobile.
2.Edit a Mobile.
3.Delete a Mobile.
4.View the Database.

Enter Your Choice
Enter the mobile ID 1

Enter the Price of mobile 123.34

Enter the Brand name of mobile Nokia

Enter the Model of mobile mynokiamobile
```

And the output I get in my database.txt file is:

```
1 123.339996 Nokia mynoki   ile
```

This space in between are random characters cant be seen here.

Answer (score 4):

You are exceeding the bounds of the memory allocated for `brand` and `Model`.

```
brand = new char[5];
model = new char[5];
```

`brand` and `mobile` are allocated 5 bytes of memory but your input is longer than that.

The values you enter are:
For `brand`: "Nokia" which is `6` bytes long( `5 + 1` additional byte is NULL terminator) &
For `model`: "mynokiamobile" which is `14` bytes long

This results in an **Undefined Behavior**.
You need to increase these freestore(heap) allocations.

A better C++ approach will be to use **[std::string](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=std%3a%3astring&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCQQFjAA&url=http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/&ei=37-rTtfzD4u7hAfYltTcDw&usg=AFQjCNHYSO65lBUum_PPFu0nJcwzb0EW9w)** instead of character arrays, but I don't know this seems like a homework exercise and maybe you are not allowed to use them, which in my understanding would be pretty lame.

Comment: hey... u got that... thanks man.. all i needed to do was allocate 50 instead of 5... thanx Als

Comment: And probably use `setw` to set the number of characters `cin` can read.

Comment: hey and one more question.. what if i write
>brand = new char;
>model = new char;

Comment: @PranayKhatri: `new` allocates the size of the `type` you pass as an parameter,if you pass `char` as the type then that will allocate `brand` & `model` with a size same as `sizeof(char)` on your system.

Comment: @PranayKhatri, no, no `new` and no `char`. `std::string`.

Answer (score 2):

Those strings are longer than 4 characters (plus the required terminating `NULL`).  And you really can't tell how many letters a user is going to input.  Using a `std::string` instead of `char[5]` might solve your problem.

When you read the file back in, you'll have to split on spaces.  See [this question for how to tokenize/split a string in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-to-split-a-string-in-c).

And see [this C++ FAQ question for how to turn strings back into numeric types](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/misc-technical-issues.html#faq-39.2), once you've split up your input strings.

Answer (score 2):

This is C++, why are you using C style strings (`brand` and `model`)?  `brand` and `model` are an array of `char`s (ie. a C style string):

```
brand = new char[5];
model = new char[5];
```

For the mobile brand you're storing "Nokia" + the NUL terminator '\0', which is 6 `char`s. For `model` you're entering in "mynokiamobile", which is well over 5 chars. I also don't understand why you'd dynamically allocate the array of fixed size with `new` either, but that's irrelevant.

Bottom line, use `std::string` and make your code more C++-like than C.

Comment: well thats ok.. but i guess this
`brand = new char;`
`model = new char;`
allocates dynamically as many characters as inputed..

Comment: @PranayKhatri it won't do that at all. It'll allocate memory for a **single** `char`. The `std::string` container will look after how much memory is required to hold your string/characters.

Comment: it doesnt allocate single char entity in my compiler... i have tried it would allocate that much bytes that you enter

Comment: @PranayKhatri `new char` allocates memory for a single `char` on the heap, `new char[X]` allocates memory for `X` `char`s. I don't think you have a magic compiler that knows how much input the user's going to type in (which is why you use `std::string` in C++).